# hypertarget with accents

Tags: hyperref, unicode, strings

with XeLaTeX (so native Unicode input), I would like to create a macro which, from a string, will create an hypertarget which anchor's name contain string.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}
\hypertarget{tête}{tête}

\hypertarget{toto}{toto}
\newpage
\hyperlink{toto}{toto}
\hyperlink{tête}{tête}


\end{document}
```

However, as this MWE illustrate, hypertarget anchor's name can't contain accents. So I suppose I should delete accent. So my question is : is there any way to provide a non-accentued version of the first argument? ideally the output should differ when coming from `tête` and from `tété`.

So maybe a command which provide a string contening all the unicode number of the sequence?

Typically, that is for cross-referencing inside index.

Comment: You could investigate what the package does in the case of accents in `\label{}` `\ref{}` arguments because those work fine.

Comment: you are right. I will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to use `\pdfstringdef`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}


\pdfstringdef\toto{tête}

\hypertarget{\toto}{tête}

\newpage
\hyperlink{\toto}{tête}

\end{document}
```

Or better to patch some internal commands of hyperref:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec,hyperref}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

    \long\def\hyper@@anchor#1#2{%
      \pdfstringdef\@temp@anchorpdfstring{#1}%
      \@hyper@@anchor\@temp@anchorpdfstring\relax#2\relax%
    }
    \def\hyperlink#1#2{%
       \pdfstringdef\@temp@anchorpdfstring{#1}%
       \hyper@@link{}{\@temp@anchorpdfstring}{#2}%
    }
\makeatother


\hypertarget{tête}{tête}

\newpage
\hyperlink{tête}{tête}

\end{document}
```

<s>I will suggest to Heiko Oberdiek to integrate directly this correction.</s>

The `\pdfstringdef` command is a very slow command, and maybe problematic with XeTeX. So make the patch only before the section you need accent in anchor name (for exemple only before indexing)

thank @cfr

Comment: I found your solution interesting but in a math mode it generate some warning like : "\pdfstringdef invalid command in math mode" or "Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding): removing `math shift' ". Is there a way to avoid this troubles ?

Comment: I don't know, I never do math…